# Bndtools: Problems preparing runtime environment

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bndtools

I installed Bndtools in Eclipse and tried out their quick tutorial: http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html

But as soon as I want to start a very simple component via the "Run OSGi" button, I receive a Launch Error prompt:

```
Status ERROR: bndtools.core code=0 At least one of the required parameters could not be detected; specify an override. Detected: osgi.native;osgi.native.osname:List<String>="null";osgi.native.osversion:Version=null;osgi.native.processor:List<String>="x86-64,amd64,em64t,x86_64", for cmd: native_capability, arguments; [native_capability] null
Status WARNING: bndtools.core code=0 No translation found for macro: native_capability, in org.example.impls null
```

The Apache Felix Gogo Shell starts at some configuration with the OSGi Framework Run setting, but the errors persist. I tried it with Eclipse Kepler and Lunar, as well as JDK 7 and 8.

I have no idea what to make of the error and warning. Something seems to be missing somewhere. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system are you running on please?

Comment: BTW the error is very unlikely to cause real problems unless you need to use bundles containing native code for your platform.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Could you please raise a bug against bnd. It looks like we haven't recognised the OS name and version or been able to map it to an OSGi capability String. Could you include the value of the Java system properties `os.name` and `os.version` in your bug report. The issue tracker is here: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues

Comment: [done](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/573)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake; this error is caused by a bug in bnd (reported here: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/573). The operating system name/version reported by Java is not recognised, as this version of bnd was released before Windows 8.1.

Aside from the error in the output there should be very little effect. You may encounter problems running bundles that contain native code, but the majority of bundles containing pure Java will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error before. Did you select an OSGi framework and Execution Env. in the run configuration?

Comment: Yes I did, the error appears on any combination of OSGi framework and Execution Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if your bnd file contains launch descriptions. Usually, the launch descriptions are defined in a different file called .bndrun file. (A bnd.bnd file can actually also act as a .bndrun file.) The bndrun file inherits properties from the workspace, not the profile.

In such scenarios - you will have to click the run button from the .bndrun file

Comment: Can you add some valuable links ?!? (to make it a better answer)

Comment: (This answers a question from two years before - bndtools probably changed *a lot*. Not saying this isn't solid advice.)